# Root path subdirectory on Prod server

Tags: javascript, html, nunjucks

I'm making a very simple static website with only Nunjuncks for helping with templating.

My gulp is running the dev env in `localhost:9000/` but the prod server will be `www.mysite.com/new/path/`.

When I deploy, all the paths and src's doesn't work, all then redirect to the root path `/` not to `/new/path/`. I know if I work with PHP I could change that on `htacess` very easy but I'm stuck on this for hours and don't find any solution for Nunjunks.

I've try to put the `<base>` on the head tag, but not even a nibble...

Answer (score 0):

Always use relative pathing for links.  Instead of leading with a slash put the location as relative to the file accessing.  If your in /new/path/myweb.html and need /images/myimage.png your path would be ../../images/myimage.png

Comment: I use, but the problem is when the site is deployed. Even with the relatives paths the links still not consider the /new/path/ sub dir